# Create table for more categories

Tags: sql-server-2005

I need to know a suitable way to create a table with this info: ID,
Category, Subcategory.

The category has more subcategories, but also I can add new sub, sub category in the future, I tried to create to two tables for category and subcategory, but I will face a vital problem in the future when I need to add a new sub sub category.

So how can solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you need to add sub sub categories and so on, you need to create only one table `categories` with `ParentCategoryID`, something like:

**`Categories`**:

- `Id`,
- `Name`,
- `ParentCategoryID`.

Then you can use recursive queries using CTE to get any Categories hierarchy tree for each sub category.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need more then 2 columns.

You just need a primary key (ID) and a foreign key (Parent ID)

```
CategoryID_PK       INT
ParentCategory_FK   INT
```

With this setup you can have an unlimited number of levels